# Sonarlint: Provide the parametrised type for this generic

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarlint-intellij

I have installed an extension called sonarlint, I am trying to refactor my code and reduce code smells, the plugin is suggesting I do further modifications like

> Raw types should not be used   Code smell   Generic types shouldn’t be
> used raw (without type parameters) in variable declarations or return
> values. Doing so bypasses generic type checking, and defers the catch
> of unsafe code to runtime.

This is one example where it complains

```
public ResponseWrapper update(TerritoryDto territoryDto) throws IOException {
    // Validate the payload
    var validationResponse = validateUpdatePayload(territoryDto);
    if (validationResponse.getCode() != HttpStatus.OK.value()) return validationResponse;
    TerritoryEntity territory = (TerritoryEntity) validationResponse.getData();

    territory.setPolygon(territoryDto.getPolygon());
    var updated = territoryRepository.save(territory);
    var erpResponse = territoryErpClient.updateTerritory(
        new UpdateTerritoryBoundary(territory.getPolygon().toString()),
        territory.getName()
    );
    if (erpResponse == null) {
        // todo - Consider sending notifications to slack about ERPNext not being reachable.
    }
    return ResponseWrapper
        .builder()
        .code(HttpStatus.OK.value())
        .message("Territory updated successfully")
        .data(TerritoryConverterInterface.TerritoryEntityToDtoMapper.INSTANCE.converter(updated))
        .build();
}
```

I tried to make modifications according to the sonarLint alert but it is not working. Please help me with this problem. Thank you all.

Comment: Which types are generic? We need to see the definitions of your types. (But I assume it is `ResponseWrapper` which is used as a raw type in the return type. Should probably be `ResponseWrapper<TerritoryDto>` or something similar. But I'm pretty sure that SonarLint has highlighted this exact location already and complained that `ResponseWrapper` is a raw type

Comment: Hi @knittl and if I use `<Object>` Instead of `<TerritoryDto>`, what is the difference?

Comment: Either callers of your method will not know which type is wrapped in the response or the code will simply fail to compile. Try it out.